# Dojo tabcontainer add custom button in tablist

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form, tabcontainer

I’m using the DOJO framework and am wondering on how to add custom stuff in the "tabbar" of the Tabcontainer Widget?

I would like to add a button in there to create a new tab.

I followed this example:

```
require(["dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TabContainer, ContentPane){
    var tc = new TabContainer({
        style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"
    }, "tc1-prog");

    var cp1 = new ContentPane({
         title: "Food",
         content: "We offer amazing food"
    });
    tc.addChild(cp1);

    var cp2 = new ContentPane({
         title: "Drinks",
         content: "We are known for our drinks."
    });
    tc.addChild(cp2);

    tc.startup();
});
```

and got this:

[image]

How can I add a third "fake" tab with a "+" sign that will add create a new tab and do *not* switch the tabview.

Here is a quick and bag sketch of what I want:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding some event handlers to your `TabContainer` and `ContentPane`. I would give you a simple flow here.

- Add a third `ContentPane` in your code with title `Add`.
- Add a `onClick` event to your `TabContainer` to track the last selected tab. If last selected tab is with title 'Add', you do nothing here. You would need the last selected tab in the next point.
- Add `onShow` event on the `ContentPane` with title 'Add' to track when this button is clicked(tab is selected). In this, you would trigger the Add new tab flow. And switch to the last selected tab that you are tracking in the `onClick` event of `TabContainer`. This would give an impression that the tab is not switched and you are actually adding a new tab.

This should provide the functionality that you are looking for.

Comment: This does not really work and is also very hacky. Somehow the events do not seem to trigger correctly. See: https://jsbin.com/wehukuquli/edit?html,output

Comment: Hi, I have edited your sample a bit. See [here](https://jsbin.com/legupovoyu/1/edit?html,output). It turns out that the `onShow` event for the third `TabContainer` is not needed here. This is kinda hacky but AFAIK, this is the only way to do it.

Comment: as you probably have seen yourself, the add button stays visually open on click. This is a screenshot from your fiddle after clicking on add: http://imgur.com/V6CubpI

Comment: I am sorry, the link i posted was incorrect. Here is the correct link: [Click Here](https://jsbin.com/xehubudixe/edit?html,output)

Comment: Oh nice, that works better than expected. Thank’s a lot Himanshu!